# simplify multiple union in sql

Tags: sql

i am trying to simply the following union query .Basically i am trying to get all the possible values from same table different column and i have to take value which are not equal to no then replace them with specific text when they are from respective column.

```
select 'a' from Mytable where a!='no' and id='1' 
 union
select 'b' from Mytable where b!='no' and id='1'
  union   select 'c' from Mytable where c!='no' and id='1'
```

so my table structure will be

```
id     Acolumn    BColumn    Ccolumn
1        123a       no         345v
```

so my expected result is 
a c

so please suggest me to simplify this query thanks in advance

Comment: Please post some sample data and needed result to clarify your need. Also, is it for Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: Replaced the conflicting product tags with generic sql. Pls add the one product tag back that you actually use.

Comment: Show your sample data and expected output. clearly specify the records available in the table for all conditions in your examples and how do you need to convert them. No images please, only text data.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you've written, this *might* be OK.

```
select case when a <> 'no' and id = '1' then 'a'
            when b <> 'no' and id = '1' then 'b'
            when c <> 'no' and id = '1' then 'c'
       end
from mytable
where (a <> 'no' and id = '1')
   or (b <> 'no' and id = '1')
   or (c <> 'no' and id = '1')
```